# How to use solr thumbnail in django on windows environment

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail, python-imaging-library

I am trying to use sorl-thumbnail to provide image thumbnails. I have followed the documentation properly.

1. I have installed `memchached` for windows, configured in the `setting.py` file.
2. I have also installed `Python Image Library`
3. I have installed `sorl-thumbnails`

I tried to use it in the templates as shown in this [example](http://thumbnail.sorl.net/examples.html#template-examples). I do not have any error, the templatetag is being loaded but when I try to display the image, it does not come up. What can be the possible reason for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're getting 404 errors since you're not getting "loud" errors.

You need to prefix the url with your static URL (or media url - wherever you've configured static files to load from). If you're using django's staticfiles app, that would be

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{ image.url }}" />
```

Comment: No there is no 404 error, the template is not processing `{% thumbnail object.image "30x30" crop="center" as im %}` at all. There seems to be some misconfiguration. What could be going wrong?

Comment: Ah, try enabling `THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = True` in your settings file and loading again - if the tag itself is failing, this should tell you why. Did you run `syncdb` after installation?

Comment: Yes I had run syncdb after installation, but it didnt create any tables. Should it have created some tables?

Comment: It is working now, apparently it had not created the table when I done syncdb the first time. But now it is working fine